# SPDY http2 + push throws exception in Angular 6 SSR

Tags: push, angular6, http2, spdy, server-side-rendering

I have Angular 6 project with SPDY http2 push and SSR enabled. When clicking around more with hard refreshes and navigating around sometimes i got these errors:

and after couple refreshes i got that weired error:

`{ AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: false == true
    at PriorityNode.removeChild (C:\git\wearlenses-3-client\web\dist\server.js:130338:3)
    at PriorityNode.remove (C:\git\wearlenses-3-client\web\dist\server.js:130326:15)
    at PriorityTree.add (C:\git\wearlenses-3-client\web\dist\server.js:130427:23)
    at Stream._initPriority (C:\git\wearlenses-3-client\web\dist\server.js:130559:25)
    at new Stream (C:\git\wearlenses-3-client\web\dist\server.js:130534:8)
    at Connection._createStream (C:\git\wearlenses-3-client\web\dist\server.js:131564:16)
    at Connection._handleHeaders (C:\git\wearlenses-3-client\web\dist\server.js:131612:21)
    at Connection._handleFrame (C:\git\wearlenses-3-client\web\dist\server.js:131495:10)
    at Parser.<anonymous> (C:\git\wearlenses-3-client\web\dist\server.js:131332:10)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (C:\git\wearlenses-3-client\web\dist\server.js:117435:31)
  generatedMessage: true,
  name: 'AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]',
  code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
  actual: false,
  expected: true,
  operator: '==' }`


`TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPriority' of null
    at C:\git\wearlenses-3-client\web\dist\server.js:130627:32
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (C:\git\wearlenses-3-client\web\dist\server.js:117435:31)
    at Zone.runTask (C:\git\wearlenses-3-client\web\dist\server.js:117202:47)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask (C:\git\wearlenses-3-client\web\dist\server.js:117510:34)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (C:\git\wearlenses-3-client\web\dist\server.js:117499:48)
    at data.args.(anonymous function) (C:\git\wearlenses-3-client\web\dist\server.js:118352:25)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:112:11)`

Here is parts of code:

```
app.get('*', (req: any, res: any) => 
{

```
try {
    Promise.all([...config.files]).then((data: any[]) => {
            for (let i = 0; i < config.files.length; i++) {
                const pushOptions = {
                    status: 200, // optional
                    method: 'GET', // optional
                    request: {
                        accept: '*/*'
                    },
                    response: {
                        'content-type': config.files[i].mimeType,
                        'Cache-Control': 'public, max-age=30672000'
                    }
                };

                let contentToSend = data[i];

                if (config.files[i].mimeType === 'application/font-woff2') {
                    contentToSend = new Buffer(contentToSend);
                    pushOptions.response['Content-Length'] = contentToSend.length;
                    pushOptions.response['Accept-Ranges'] = 'bytes';
                }

                if (config.files[i].gzip) {
                    pushOptions.response['content-encoding'] = 'gzip';
                    contentToSend = zlib.gzipSync(contentToSend);
                }

                const stream = (<any>res).push(`/${config.files[i].name}`, pushOptions);

                stream.on('error', () => { });

                stream.end(contentToSend);
            }
        }).catch(error => { });
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}


res.render('index', { req });
```

});
```

I feel like there should be res.render in another place but if i try to put it after `stream.end` performance drops.

What I should do differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue. This is some bug and quick fix for this is:

```
let fs = require('fs')
let path = require('path')
let file = path.join(
    process.cwd(),
    'node_modules/spdy-transport/lib/spdy-transport/priority.js'
)

let data = fs
    .readFileSync(file)
    .toString()
    .split('\n')
if (data.length < 190) {
    data.splice(73, 0, '/*')
    data.splice(75, 0, '*/')
    data.splice(
        187,
        0,
        `
    var index = utils.binarySearch(this.list, node, compareChildren);
    this.list.splice(index, 1);
`
    )
    let text = data.join('\n')

    fs.writeFile(file, text, function(err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err)
    })
}
```

sources where taken from:

```
https://github.com/spdy-http2/spdy-transport/issues/47
https://github.com/Noumenae/server/issues/20
https://github.com/spdy-http2/node-spdy/issues/285
https://github.com/spdy-http2/node-spdy/issues/244
```

As far as I understood everybody just wait for Express 5 which will have natvie http2 support.